# JSON data printing issue in react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

This is my JSON Data

```
const Paper = [{ Head: "<strong>Heading Content</strong>sub-heading", content: ["sample texts...."] }];
```

And i try to print this data to my page it working but it show like `<strong>Heading Content- </strong>subheading`

```
{Paper.map((Paper) => (
  <div className='news-papper'>
    {Head}
  </div>
))}
```

I wand " **Heading Content-** subheading "
How to print data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the property `Head` of `Paper` object, and don't forget to name the array `Papers` with (s) at the end, since it'is an array contains many `Paper`.

```js
{Papers.map((Paper) => (
  <div className='news-papper' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Paper.Head}}/>
))}
```

> PS: `Papers`'s not in format JSON, instead it is an array of object in
> JS.

Comment: that working , the data print like <strong>Heading Content- </strong>subheading , the strong tag is print in page not show the style of strong

Comment: You can use  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: is it worked for you, or I will implement `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for you

Comment: its working i will implement